# XML Sitemaps - Is there a good reason to create and manage XML Sitemaps?

Tags: xml, seo, sitemap

I am beginning a new web project that will have about thirty sites. Each site will have 50 - 100 pages of content that is always being added to, so no content is ever going away.

I am interested in creating database driven XML sitemaps to help the search engines find our pages quickly.

Do XML sitemaps actually do much good, assuming that all of your content as available through links?  What are the benefits of using an XML sitemap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sitemap is just another way to let search engines find your content. If your content can be found through internal linking, like from an HTML sitemap, then there isn't a tremendous need to have a sitemap. But it is a good, albeit redundant, way to make sure search engines can find your content.

Comment: So, if you KNOW that you have links to every page to your site, then XML sitemaps just create extra work with no real benefit?

Comment: What about a sitemaps's priority level? Do search engines respect that?

Comment: They do offer a benefit as it is a great way to tell search engines about your content especially if a site is having difficulty getting pages indexed. The priority level isn't really used for anything as of right now. I leave them off of my sitemaps so they are lighter and easier to manage.

Comment: So, you are suggesting just using the URLs in the sitemap?

Comment: That's all I use. Until the others prove to be important in some way I don't waste any time with them.